# When to approach potential PhD supervisors while bonded to a private company?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, physics

I am serving a 1 year bond in my company that paid the expenses for my masters program, which stipulates that I have to serve the bond for a year on the date of my completion. It has been 3 to 4 months since I have completed my studies and I wonder when would be the right time to approach potential supervisors of a different University, as **I have another 8 months left to serve the bond**.

The PhD application is open throughout the year.
I am wondering **when would be the right time to approach the supervisor** since realistically I could only join in only 8 months later?

Should I approach when I have another 2 months left to serve the bond, maybe sooner, or maybe I could correspond with the PhD supervisor even now?

Comment: Actually, eight months doesn't seem like a long time to me. And two months seems far too short. Just be clear about when you can start.

Comment: What part of the world are you in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you contact prospective supervisors you should first have a look at the preferred practice in the university you are going to apply to --- some universities discourage contact with prospective supervisors prior to program entry and others require it.  Assuming that contact with prospective supervisors prior to entry is okay, it would be perfectly fine (even desirable) to have early contact.  A period of eight months prior to entry is desirable since it gives the prospective supervisor time to interview you, scrutinise your work and proposed research, seek revisions, and contact your referees (again, universities vary on these practices).

Comment: From what I've read on the university page and the professors page they do encourage direct contact with the professor. Thanks for the swift reply

Answer (score 0):

When a PhD position is open, it is expected to be filled as soon as possible.

However, as soon as possible means at minimum 4 months (opening the positions, receiveing applications, screening candidates, interviewing them ....) more realistically 6 months.

Assuming you apply now and that you are called for an interview in one month from now, it would not be unusual you will be asked "when will you be available to begin the position?".

Unless your answer is "in 2 years starting from now" it is quite likely that saying in "~7 months from now" is not going to have influence on the decision: if you will be the picked candidate, they know you will be available in 7 months, and that's all.

To clarify the matter, you can contact the secretary or other similar-HR position, since it is a rolling open position, they should be able to provide an answer, without you bothering the professor. You may discover the PhD has teaching duties so there are preferred starting times (thanks @GEdgar).

Comment: If a PhD position has teaching duties, then the starting time is likely synchronized with the academic calendar.

Comment: @GEdgar oh thanks for the reminder about the teaching duties as well !